# First Posts and Late Answers queues nearly always empty

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently earned the priviledge to review [first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers). I'd like to contribute, but I rarely get the opportunity to review a post.

Don't get me wrong: I think it's great that the community is so diligent in handling the review tasks.

However, if I look at the "Top Questions" in the [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/) then I can find a lot of "second posts" from users with one-digit reputation scores that would clearly benefit from a review.

That brings me to the question: Wouldn't it make sense to add some posts from users with low reputation scores to said queues if they run empty?

Of course, I can edit those posts anyway (and I do), but handling review tasks motivates me more.

Comment: Number of reviewers is quite high in comparison to the number that arrives in these queues.  That should explain what you observe.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. This is why I ask whether it would make sense to add more posts to these queues in a meaningful way.

Comment: How can more posts be added?  The number of posts in these queues is limited by the _actual_ number of posts.

Comment: As I understood, only first posts of new users are added to these queues. Why not also adding second posts, for example? Please correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Questions shouldn't be added just because the queues are empty.  Either they need to be reviewed or they don't.  I tend to think that just beause it is "a 2nd post" that it automatically needs reviewed, but possibly a metric based on the success (or failure) of the first post, it should trigger a review.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant: If a user still has a one-digit reputation score when posting his second post then I assume that the first post was not that "successful". But applying a more sophisticated metric, as you propose, sounds even better!

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Questions shouldn't be added just because the queues are empty", I cannot agree with that entirely. If the queues are empty, it means the community can handle more review work. More review work done means that low quality content gets removed more efficiently and general quality improves. That said, you are right in saying that there's no point in placing suspicion on a post just because it's a user's second post only. It's just that the filters that let stuff into the review queue can be loosened a little, so that more reviews are triggered, like you also said.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I didn't highlight it, but the emphasis on that sentence is **just because the queues are empty**.  I was responding to the OP's "...if they run empty" statement.  If we want to review more posts, then add more criteria to send more posts to the queue, but don't just decide to add something only because the queue is empty.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, I agree when you put it like that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is one way we could expand these review queues, now that they're consistently sitting empty, and that's to increase the number of reviews required for a post to be removed from these two queues.

I've been watching the First Posts and Late Answers queue for a while, and even with audits and other ways of educating reviewers, you still occasionally get bad reviewers who approve spam or non-answers. If only one review is required to remove an item from a review queue, all it takes is one bad review to allow spam to slip through.

If we were to increase this to two reviews (or more) before something was dequeued, that would give reviewers more to do in those queues while adding a safety net to catch bad reviews. Multiple reviews are required for the Low Quality Posts queue, and that seems to be working out well right now.

I know that this has been discussed among the developers before, but now might be the time to put this into place.

Comment: But spam would still get through. Suggested edits requires 3 or 6 votes to be either approved or rejected and there are still edits that are approved that shouldn't be.

Comment: @Howlin - From my observations, only a very small number of spam posts make it through review, as compared to suggested edits (for which there usually is a lot more grey area) even with only one reviewer in most cases. For spam that gets two reviews (such as a post that hits both First Posts and Late Answers review queues), even if it is missed by one reviewer, it almost always is caught by the other. It's a lot easier to spot non-answers and spam than bad edits.

Comment: I still prefer honk and @psubsee2003's suggestions in the comments: Add second posts from new users who didn't have good first posts.

Comment: In general the number of reviewers should scale with the square root of the number of active members of the site (that is, some small constant fraction of that square root).

Comment: @Brad: How are the chances that "now might be the time" turns into "now is the time"?

Comment: @honk - Unfortunately, only the developers could know that. I'm just a janitor.