# Why does it take four clicks to close an already-flagged duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

**Many questions are obvious duplicates and have already been flagged as such. Why then isn't it a single click for reviewers to confirm this and close them?**

It seems like it's more work to vote to close them than it is for a questioner to post another dupe.

askubuntu.com, to take just one example, has 777 close-votes in the review question at present.

For each of them I have to

1. click *close*
2. *as duplicate*
3. wait a few seconds for it to load, then choose the duplicate
4. then *OK*.

I can see it's useful to identify what it's a duplicate of. However, when that information is already in a comment and has been identified by the flagger and multiple reviewers, what purpose does it serve to make additional reviewers do it again?

**Why not just one button per bad question: *yes, it's a dupe*?**

---

Some answers raise the point that "sometimes the flagger was wrong and it's not a dupe of the suggested question", or "sometimes there's more than one possibility". This can certainly happen. However it seems to me that it happens in a minority of cases, and even fewer when multiple reviewers have already confirmed it. So perhaps it's worth adding a fast-path?

My impression is, 90% of the time when the question is flagged as a dupe, it is in fact a dupe of the nominated question.

Maybe it would be better to make the simple case fast, so reviewer time can be concentrated on edge cases?

Comment: Downvotes without comment, how nice.

Comment: It's also a meta-site thing; downvotes (especially on feature-requests) can also signal disagreement.

Comment: @DennisMeng fair enough - there are four people who... like it being slow to close garbage questions? Or feel there would be deleterious consequences for making it faster? Is there something I could read to understand that point of view?

Comment: I imagine more of the latter. (I have to admit, it *would* be nice if someone did actually spell out their reasons why they don't think this would be a good idea. I'll write up a post with my reasons for disagreeing with this feature request.)

Comment: I will be especially interested if those reasons justify the tradeoff against hundreds of mostly-duplicate questions remaining open, flaggers feeling neglected, reviewers frustrated, etc.

Comment: This seems like a wholly bad idea, it would effectively reduce the decision as to whether a question is a duplicate to the first voter (because subsequent badge-hungry voters will just click "yep", "yep, "yep"). Is it really such a bad thing that it takes a minimum of ~5s to confirm you agree with the pre-selected duplicate?

Comment: The hidden assumption there is that you're getting better results by making people click four times rather than once, and I doubt it. Is it such a bad thing? No, not really, I'm just slightly sad SO I'd being downed in a flood of effluent.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have to respectfully disagree with this feature request.

If we're going to allow this, what's to stop allowing something similar for any of the other close reasons? What would the UI look like if more than one of these apply? Making something like that look good (or even just decent) is nontrivial.

As an extension to that, what if there are two dupe candidates? (Say, two questions, each with two corresponding close votes and X number of flags) How are you going to allow both options at once?

As far as UI goes in the review queue, right now we have the four buttons in the top right:

- Leave Open
- Close
- Edit
- Skip

I've already seen plenty of "Oops, I pressed the wrong button" posts; adding more buttons here is only going to increase the risks. If we do a special-case on flags, then we're not really reviewing questions anymore, but flags. Reviewing flags is its own animal altogether, and I'm not a fan of mixing things if I can help it.

---

I know the last part of the question asked about a one-click option, but since the title asks why we have to click four times, I'll go ahead and address why I think 2 or 3 clicks aren't feasible either.

Right now, if you choose to vote to close, there's three more steps afterward:

- Choose why you're voting to close

Again, I don't agree with pulling out the close reasons and adding more buttons, so this click stays.

- Narrow down your reason (applies to duplicate and off-topic close reasons)

This one also stays, since if there are multiple possible questions that fit the bill you need to pick which one. (Plus, maybe you just happen to want to use a different question.)

- One more button to confirm your choice

Right now, for any vote to close, you have to confirm. I personally want to keep this, since there's *always* the risk of making a mistake. If I have to spend an extra split-second every time to lower the risks, then so be it.

---

Finally, as I started typing this up, you said this in the comments:

> I will be especially interested if those reasons justify the tradeoff
>   against hundreds of mostly-duplicate questions remaining open,
>   flaggers feeling neglected, reviewers frustrated, etc.

Look, I get it. We're all sick of the avalanche of terrible questions, and we'd love to deal with them swiftly and efficiently. However, the most important thing that I think we should keep in mind is that if we're going to deal with this, **we must continue to show the same kind of high quality in our close actions that we're expecting out of questions.** Basically, we have to make sure we don't stoop to their level while we're cleaning up.

The short answer to why I disagree with the feature request is then: While I agree that it's nice to make reviewing close votes easier to handle, we need to keep our votes as high quality as we can. I can't get behind this feature request because I just don't foresee a feature like this *not* causing a quality-hit as well.

Comment: Adding "are you sure?" steps to frequently-executed operations is not a great way to reduce operator errors. It's better to allow people to undo mistakes and that seems eminently possible here.

Comment: Adding an undo functionality opens up a different can of worms though.

Comment: _"What would the UI look like?"_ I'd imagine a list of the flags and a single button click to agree with them, as well as the existing options to make some other decision. It should let you click through to or unfold the alleged dupe. But, anyhow, +1 for the thoughtful response, thanks.

Comment: Optimizing for the quality of individual votes (which I doubt this does) is not a good solution for overall site quality in the face of this avalanche that's repulsing good participants. I don't know if even the most aggressive question-closing would really help, but rejecting questions too easily is probably not in the top 10 SO problems today.

Answer (score 1):

Because some of those "obvious" duplicates can be (and often are) incorrect.  Or, they could be covering one aspect of the problem, but not another aspect, which is covered in another question.

Merely going along with the crowd on "this is a duplicate" *can* be helpful, but there are times in which the duplicate selected simply isn't appropriate.

Yes, it may require a few extra clicks, but that gives one a moment of time to be sure that the duplicate actually answers the posed question.

Comment: Any sense of the prior likelihood they're incorrect? I think it's ~<10%.

Comment: I think it's ~>99.9%

Comment: @Pat, Really, almost all "flag as dupes" are incorrect? Your experience is vastly different to mine, both as a flagger and reviewer.

Comment: @poolie I thought we were coming up with numbers? :P

Comment: @Pat I'm just trying to work out if you're joking, or reading it backwards.

Comment: @poolie yes, I am.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no good reason why it needs four clicks, but fixing this is unlikely to really fix the problems with bad questions.**

Manually closing, after a delay, bad questions probably won't stop them, even if it's made more efficient, and it uses up experienced-contributor time.

There are other suggestions looking at the quality problem, and the crowding-out of good-users with bad:

- [Gamification rules have to be changed. Aiming quality, not quantity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256742/gamification-rules-have-to-be-changed-aiming-quality-not-quantity)
- [More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no)
- [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)
- [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

The actual answer to my underlying question is to just break my habit of trying to review or answer questions, unless I have a real interest in that particular question, and then I'll no longer feel frustrated.

Comment: See also,http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251987/243712