# Should comments saying "google it." be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I saw a comment just now saying "google it dude"

IMHO, it is not helpful either to the OP or to other readers.
[image]

Am I alone here? Or is it Ok to respond to people with "Google it" as a comment?

Not sure, I can see both sides... *but* I lean towards a bit more restrained.

Comment: If you're willing to spend the time to tell someone to 'Google it' in a comment, you have more than enough time to Google it yourself, and then link an appropriate answer to it.

Comment: @Compass Sure, but then the author wouldn't have known that they were posting a question that was trivially googlable, and they would learn that those types of questions are appropriate here, when the reality is the opposite.  It doesn't need to be about saving time.

Comment: I'm thoroughy pissed off with Google-slavery. I'm convinced that most of such OP's just want a unique answer for their homework and are using SO contributors to extract them.  I refuse to waste time on such questions, not even on posting links. 'I searched on the web/Google/documentation and couldn't find anything' is a 99.9% touchstone for 'do my work for me, I can't be bothered'.

Comment: SO appears to emphasize quantity over quality as so many similar questions get upvoted highly and answerers rewarded. I don't think this will ever [change](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256742/gamification-rules-have-to-be-changed-aiming-quality-not-quantity).

Comment: In many cases "googling it" produces a StackOverflow page as the top result(s) so I think it would be more productive to have some answers available for people rather than telling them to do something they have already done.

Comment: @dmeehan You might want to read this Meta post: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280328/did-google-recently-update-algorithms-in-a-way-thats-bad-for-stack-overflow-que/280370#comment130291_280370. Oh, and it's 'Stack Overflow', not 'StackOverflow'.

Comment: Actually, looking at the top left of the page (normal and meta), it's 'stackoverflow'

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: @Servy: Use comments of the form `[Top <favorite search engine> result](<link to best first page search result>)`

Comment: @dmeehan: In the worst cases, googling it _used_ to provide a great answer, but now it provides the very SO question that was asked as the top link. In one case, a question I answered a couple years, I don't think I'd be able to answer again, as my original Google terms now turn up the question I answered, 4 followup questions, 8 questions where someone just copied the code from the answer, 1 github repo with a port of the code to another language, and 17 blog posts copying either my code or the port; wherever I found the original information that allowed me to write that code, it's lost.

Comment: @abarnert: That's kinda scary. So how do we prevent Stack Exchange questions and answers masking the very resources we use when creating our answers? I guess we could always include links to the sources we use, and _hopefully_ some of those links will still be relevant further down the track.

Comment: Although people might hate me for saying this, **Googling is difficult**.  Not actually typing a phrase into Google, not even pressing the <enter> key/clicking, but deciding what to type.  There are some questions that can't be condensed into a few keywords without specialist knowledge.  I asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330331/how-do-i-optimally-distribute-values-over-an-array-of-percentages) which is like that.  Although the example question given is certainly not that case, this happens more often than people think.  Obvious to you != Obvious to OP.  Off topic?

Comment: It appears you forgot to (down)vote the question. That's far more important than flagging some harmless comment.

Comment: Tbh as a peson who gets questions which are just a Google search away I would love to see a close reason of "Just Google it". You answer one Google question and that user comes back for more. You need tio be firm and tell them that we are not here to do their work for them, they need should Google and then come to us.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert if your question cannot be found by yourself on Google search then that is fine but, for the 90% of questions which are a Google search away, it is normally that they come to us before going Google.

Comment: Not a duplicate because users can't edit comments; and the other post specifically addresses answers. The guidance is different, so this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: An assumed, implicit, unstated and probably under discussed goal of stack exchange is to do better than google. I look forward to the day when all of human knowledge is on stack exchange and we can turn off google. Telling people to JFGI is delaying that glorious day.

Comment: @Compass I was specifically downvoted and commented on one of my answers which listed some of the top results searching for the very things the asker said they had googled (which they obviously hadn't)

Comment: I would love to have a close reason *"I googled for your literal question title and found these exact duplicates/this official documentation/this excellent tutorial (linkA, linkB, linkC) on the first page of the results"*. If that would exist, I wouldn't have to type such comments myself whenever I felt that just "Duplicate" isn't strong enough.

Comment: Duplicate of 2011's http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87652/discourage-google-for-it-answers

Answer (score 124):

Personally I'd flag such comments as *not constructive*.

The comment is indeed not helpful, not to the OP and not to future visitors. Either show how googling it would have found the information, or not comment at all.

Comment: In particular, it's definitely *not* useful in this case as the question explicitly states that the OP *has* tried searching.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: If  you have a view on this subject, please post an answer. If you disagree with Martijn's answer, please post it as an answer. The Comments are not to argue with someone about why their answer is wrong; and certainly not to have an extended discussion about the merits of an answer. Going back and forth in the comments doesn't provide the same visibility; and it directs it at the wrong person. If those involved are interested in continuing the comment discussion here, [it can be found in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67045).

Comment: It is however useful as the comment explaining why the question was closed.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ "Easily Google-able" is not (and has never been) a reason to close a question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker but the lack of minimal understanding was (once).

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ Nope. It was for questions where no answer would help because the user simply didn't understand enough about the problem to make use of the answer. "Googling it" may be an effect, but it wasn't the cause.  That close reason was abused because others thought the same way you do, and thus removed.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker OK, it's high-time that "Easily Google-able" became a reason to close a question.

Comment: @MartinJames there are a number of mets posts on the subject; but if you've got a new angle on it, you should post a meta question or contribute to one of the posts on the subject.

Comment: @George: _"Nope. It was for questions where..._" That's ludicrous! That notion depends entirely on the notion that each Q&A is _only_ for the benefit of the OP, which is patently false. Also I don't think I've ever heard that particular angle before.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so you missed this? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: No, I remember it well. Which part of it states that "it was for questions where no answer would help because the user simply didn't understand enough about the problem to make use of the answer"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The First link points to this question, and then this answer written by jmac: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/16587 Since I don't know whether you read that, here it is, quoting jmac's answer: `I think the fundamental issue is that this is being used to say, "You are clueless beyond anyone's ability to help you", and there is no way to explain that nicely [...]` . So yea, 'minimal understanding' was supposed to be for that; but was used for 'easily googeable'. We tried out easily googeable, but got rid of it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: _"You are clueless beyond anyone's ability to help you"_ is not quite the same as what you said. Furthermore, _"this is being used to say"_ is not at all the same as _"this is for"_ — it's a matter of designed-for versus used-for. By my interpretation, jmac was [correctly] identifying how people actually used the close vote reason (and went as far as to call this trend an "issue" i.e. a problem), not describing the intention of the close reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Here's even more for you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/ `...but every time I ask someone else to interpret them, I hear, "Oh, those are for questions that don't show enough effort".`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and Of course, Shog's answer to that question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210868/16587

Comment: It is very useful for future visitors if it stops unwanted behaviour. Sure, a downvote is supposed to send the same signal, but new users do not know this.

Comment: @MartinJames I disagree, because often the StackOverflow question will become the top Google result. Going from Google to StackOverflow and seeing "you should have googled this" is disheartening.

Answer (score 37):

My answer is addressing the specific cross-section of comments that are there to *supposedly* help a user find their answer, like this one. Other types of comments are out of scope for this advice and answer.

If a user posts a comment that is 'not constructive', I'll generally delete it, [contrary to Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280428/16587).

If you see a comment that can generally be construed as not constructive, flag it.

This is one such comment.

In this case; the comment in particular is not constructive. "Google it" is in the same vein as "Read a book on it!". The only difference is the medium and the access.

If you want such a comment to stick around, provide some actual help in the form of:

- A link that contains the information the user needs to solve their issue
- A specific book recommendation, with specific location of the information you believe will help the user
- a specific thing to look for.

In short, be actionable in your words. If the user can't take what you're writing and use it to solve their issue, *why are you writing it in the first place?*

As a moderator, I typically see these types of comments flagged, and generally they'll be flagged as:

- Not helpful (custom)
- Not Constructive
- Rude

All of these are valid reasons to flag these types of comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67044/discussion-on-answer-by-george-stocker-should-comments-saying-google-it-be-fl).

Comment: The question is not good because it doesn't show any of the search terms used in the Google search.  The 'Google it' comment is not constructive in this context because it doesn't specify a suitable search term.  In other contexts, a suggested Google search can, I believe, be constructive.  For example, when telling people not to use the C function `gets()`, I usually note that "the first Internet worm exploited `gets()` (Google search 'morris internet worm')".  This let's them find what I'm talking about if they want to know more.

Answer (score 14):

The example that you gave is not a constructive comment, but similar comments telling people to Google things can be constructive given that you actually provide some helpful information.

The problem with the comment in your example is the same problem with questions that tell you that "it doesn't work".  The reader might doesn't know what "**it**" is, and if they do know, they still probably aren't getting any value out of "google it".

If you know of a library, then it's perfectly fine to tell the OP to google the details.  If you know what search keywords will result in better googling, then it's perfectly fine to tell the op to try googling those keywords.

---

As a rule of thumb:  If you feel like you're dismissing a user or somehow telling them off for making a bad post, then your comment is probably not constructive.  If you're not making a good faith attempt to help the OP solve their problem, then you should probably think twice about leaving a comment at all.  If you think the question is bad, then downvote, closevote, flag if it needs moderator attention , and move on.

Comment: If you think that a question is bad, then posting a comment explaining to the author *why* it's bad, in addition to downvoting/closing/flagging is *helpful*.  It's not something that should be actively discouraged, as it inhibits the authors ability to learn from the experience or solve the problem.

Comment: @GrantWinney You think that 90% of questions asked would be trivially solved by the author running the question through Google/the documentation?  I'm sure it's a fair number, but 90% it is not.  If the question *is* trivially solved by running it through google, or just lookup up the section of the documentation of the topic at hand *then the question isn't an appropriate SO question*.  SO is here for questions that *aren't* answered by a simple google search, or a check of the documentation.  RTFM is problematic in that it conveys the information rudely.

Comment: @GrantWinney If the user feels that the post deserves a downvote/close vote and decides to post a comment *as well* to explain the problem to the OP then why go out of your way to *delete* that comment?  While it's certainly appropriate for people to be *able* to anonymously downvote, we don't want to *require* people to *only* downvote/closevote on bad posts.

Comment: @Servy There's a difference between telling the OP the real thing problem with the post such as "there's a duplicate here", or "you don't have information x" and a stock dismissal such as "google it"

Comment: @GrantWinney Agreed.  It's why I almost wish less meta posts provided examples (when attempting to discuss a generalized policy).

Comment: @SamIam Sure, but I don't see how the differences are particularly relevant.  I just don't see particularly significant differences between, "you shouldn't be posting questions on SO without having searched through Google first" and "you can find the answer to this question by putting searching it on Google".  The OP gets pretty much all the same information from both comments.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the *only* valid reason for suggesting someone use a search engine (and by the way, I always use the generic term "search engine" because there are other, arguably better search engines than Google) is when you can suggest search terms that may not have occurred to the original user AND that bring up good results.  And you will only know that if you actually attempt a search using those terms.

The real problem with telling someone to "Google it" is that you *assume* they have not done that already (with perhaps the underlying *assumption* that they are just being lazy), you *assume* that Google will give them the best results, and you *assume* that they will use (or have used) a search string that will bring up useful and relevant results, preferably on the first page, but at least within the first four or five pages.  All of these can be faulty assumptions, but the fact is that many people simply have no idea what search phrase to use to get useful results.  What seems an entirely obvious search string to one person may not be at all obvious to someone else.

So if you just tell someone to Google it without saying much of anything else, you are pretty much just being a jerk, and I would definitely **not** consider such a response as helpful or constructive.

Comment: And if searching for the exact text of the question asked yields lots of quality search results?  What then?  Your post assumes that everyone posting a question will have already done everything they can to search for a good result.  Some have, but the reality is some haven't.  When you know that searching for the question asked will yield good results, it's appropriate to say so.  If someone is incorrect in saying that such a search will yield good results, then the comment is no different from any other factually incorrect comment.  (Note that's not a reason for deletion.)

Comment: Unfortunately, experience tells me that all of those assumptions are, 90% of the time, spot on.

Comment: And just like "my code doesn't work" without showing the code is pretty much useless, saying "I googled it" without indicating what search terms you used or what you had a hard time understanding in the results is useless.

Comment: Also, Google provides different answers for different people (depending of geography, prior search history, and other data that they use to guess what you actually are looking for.)

Answer (score 10):

I think in general, this is not constructive. In this particular case, it's *definitely* not constructive. The asker explicitly says he tried googling it, so telling him "google it" means you didn't even read the question.* It's mostly used on stupid questions that should be downvoted to oblivion and/or closed. Downvoting and closing is all you need to do; adding a comment that does nothing but insult the user doesn't help.**

---

However, there are cases where "Google it" can be a useful comment. For example, imagine you've written this comment:

> You can't do this with the high-level libfrotz API; you need to use the low-level API. It's impossible to even get you started until you read a tutorial on the basics of that API.

… or:

> There's no way to answer this question, because Python objects don't work like that. There *is* no prototype to access; objects are instances of *classes*. You need a tutorial on class-based OO, whether Python-specific or general.

Typically, the response is:

> @commenter: Where do I find a tutorial?

Even if I knew which of the 3 low-level Frotz tutorials or 69105 class-based OO tutorials was the best one for the asker (which I almost certainly don't), recommending off-site resources is explicitly listed as one of the things SO is not good for. As soon as I recommended one, someone else would say, "No, use this one instead." So the best response is:

> Google it.

---

<sub>* Unless you're trying to call the asker a liar, but if it's important enough to say that, say it directly: "You claim you tried googling it, but I don't believe you. When I google the exact same thing, the first result is exactly what you say you can't find."</sub>

<sub>** Adding a comment to *help* the user is a different story. But in a case like this, nobody's trying to help.</sub>

Comment: If you're going to say "Google it", I recommend giving a suggested set of search terms ("Google search 'python frotz tutorials'", for example).  It may be obvious to you which search will work, but it may not be obvious to the other people that if you leave out 'python' for the search term, you get a load of irrelevant items.

Answer (score 3):

maybe the OP had googled, but wasn't sure of what they were looking for and although they maybe found some documentation, they didn't understand it.

A question on SO can provide much more succinct answers and examples that can help someone learn, i've found SO to be much better in many cases than the official documentation on certain topics.

Comments that are just google it are insulting and can be unwelcoming to newbies who might just end going away and never posting or contributing to the network again, surely the idea of SO is to gain more people, more questions more answers more community more everything.

just my 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, a personalized answer to your specific question can be more concise. But if they found the info but didn't understand it, they should have linked it, and pointed out exactly what they think they understood and where they just don't get it yet. That is also highly advisable to foreclose answers being equally unintelligible to them.

Answer (score 1):

In general it may not be constructive.  However I just voted to close a question as a duplicate because I googled for the answer and found a duplicate SO question.  In this case I don't think an additional comment noting that the duplicate question was found using Google should be flagged but rather may help to enlighten the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think these comments *can* be legitimate and useful, both as a way of helping the asker become better at solving their own problems and a way of publicly chastising them and communicating to future visitors that we expect  at least a basic attempt at research to be done before asking here. Even posting such a comment on a question where the asker has claimed "I Googled and didn't find anything" can be acceptable, in my eyes.

But this question is an ***absolutely terrible example***. An ideal "Google it" comment should meet these criteria:

1. Be posted on a question that is genuinely easy to Google
2. Indicate what search terms would yield the answer
3. Link to an example of a page containing the answer that could be reached via the search

For example, a comment along these lines I would argue is definitely constructive, despite its chastising tone:

> You claim to have tried to Google this, but you don't seem to have tried very hard. Pasting your question title into Google yields the API docs at http://docs.fooscriptplusplus.com/Widget/frobnicate as the second result, and the answer to your question is in the first paragraph.

But the question screenshotted here fails the very first condition. As a couple of others here have pointed out, the term the asker wants defined doesn't exist (at least in the field of programming - it [has meaning to epistemologists and metaphysicists](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/)). So the definition is clearly not trivially Googleable. Worse, the commenter points the user to the Java docs, thereby sending them on even more of a fool's errand that had they merely sent the OP to Google.

As an aside, this illustrates pretty clearly one reason why a "trivially Googleable" close reason would never work. The commenter here came across a question to which he didn't know the answer, and didn't know where to find the answer, and which the asker claimed to have already Googled. Despite that - and evidently without making any attempt to Google the question themself - he felt it reasonable to chastise the asker for failing to Google before asking. Allowing questions to be closed for being trivally Googleable might be workable if we could trust people to *actually identify those questions reliably*, but we clearly can't.

Answer (score -21):

It's a perfectly fine comment.  There's certainly no reason to remove it.  The person not knowing that the question they are asking is well documented and that solutions would be found using the terms already being used.

Now, it's certainly not a suitable SO-quality answer, and it's not an *amazing* comment with a huge amount of value, but it's certainly not harmful so long as it stays polite about it.  There's no reason to go out of your way to flag the comment unless it is rude in how it goes about stating it.

The comment also provides information to both the author and other readers indicting that it is lacking in sufficient research effort, but it does so in a somewhat more productive way than just saying, "you didn't do enough research".

Comment: +1. It can be surprising to find that some people do not appreciate how much they can learn by simply searching for information. Yes, of course it can help more to *also* point to some such specific info found by googling in the given context. But even the occasional *lmgtfy* can, in fact, be helpful. There is no hard-and-fast rule (never do it; always do it) that should govern this - it's a judgment thing. The point is to try to help people, and yes, sometimes (not often, but sometimes) that can mean pointing them toward Google.

Comment: The question includes "I've tried googling". How is saying "Try googling" helpful in the slightest? In this case, the problem is that the term the OP is looking for isn't a legitimate one in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet This question (and my answer) is about the general case, not just this specific case.  As to this specific case though, it *doesn't* just say google it, it also specifically mentions the documentation as a good source.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's also worth noting that saying that you did do research is radically different than demonstrating that you've done it.  Just because someone says that they did research doesn't mean that they did, nor is it particularly helpful information.  Them indicating what types of things they found, and what problems they had with those results would both demonstrate that they did do the research, and give answerers a much stronger understanding of the problem the OP is having.  Duplicating the common google results isn't helpful either for someone that actually did search.

Comment: @Servy: of course including *I googled and googled and didn't find nuttin* is never good enough. But to respond with *google it dude* is still not going to be constructive. When is *Look again* a constructive response to *I looked in the phone directory for the number*?

Comment: It mentions the documentation *as if* it's a good source, when it's not. So even if it gives the *appearance* of being helpful, it's a red herring. I still don't see anything good about that particular comment on this particular question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters When you know that the number is there and that the person just missed it.  It's exactly the response that I'd expect from someone who knew that I just skipped over the number.  I wouldn't expect them to take the phone book from me and look it up and assume that I'm utterly incapable of looking up the number.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then you feel that that one comment is problematic because it's suggesting the use of a resource you consider poor.  That's certainly a valid critique of the comment.  It's not grounds for deletion, but it's certainly a good reason to post another comment.

Comment: @Servy: I don't consider the resource to be poor at all. I consider the *comment* to be poor because it implies that the documentation will define that term, when in fact it won't. It's not a constructive comment - just the opposite - which is why I flagged it as not constructive. It seems to me that the commenter reacted without actually trying their suggestion themselves.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant a poor resource *for answering this question*, not in general.

Comment: Right. So the comment is suggesting doing things that won't help. That doesn't sound constructive to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet Making *this one example* an example of a comment that you don't think is helpful.  I don't disagree with that at all.  Again, the core of my answer is discussing the general case, not this one example.

Comment: Devil's advocate here: saying "I googled it" is just a common a lie as "I tried everything" on Stack. People may disagree, but I feel this is a valid comment, especially because there are several questions a day (understatement) where googling the title yields the answer. On a question that was asked well, I'd help the OP find the information, but on an obvious lack of attempt question this is many people's go-to comment

Comment: ^^ what @SterlingArcher says.  Students are taking SO contributors for a ride.  Ask them for a list of links that they searched, they go silent because most of them are bone-idle, deadbeat vampires.

Comment: Indeed @SterlingArcher is spot on! In an ideal world all our question askers would be lovely people who have done their best to solve their problem but, "on the ground" so to speak, that's not at all what we see on a daily basis. I get that you want us to assume good faith, but from my experience on SO I've no reason to assume good unlaziness.

Comment: @SterlingArcher While what you say about "I googled it" being a common lie makes perfect sense and may be true in most cases, it seems to me that the user asking the question quoted by OP was genuinely confused by what is essentially a misnomer whereas the user answering "google it" didn't even read the question carefully enough to realize that. (No, the Java documentation doesn't help you with abstract objects, because there's no such thing as an abstract object.)

Comment: @SterlingArcher Perhaps more importantly, a lack of effort on the part of the user asking a question doesn't make a "Google it" comment appropriate in any way. An unhelpful comment remains unhelpful even if it turns out it was posted to a bad question asked by a lazy person.

Comment: @laszlok Yes, actually, that *does* make the comment appropriate.  When a post violates the rules and expectations of an appropriate question, posting a comment telling them that they've violated the rules and informing them what they did wrong and how to address it *is* being helpful.  Deleting a comment informing a question author of why their question is a poor quality/lazy question is actively harmful.  If they don't know that they did something wrong, they can't fix it.

Comment: @Servy If the comment said "you need to do more research before you post your question", it would be helpful. I appreciate that for some people, "Google it" means the same thing, but that's not true for everyone, and especially not for newcomers who might make this sort of mistake, therefore I stand by my opinion that it is unhelpful and inappropriate.

Comment: @laszlok How does it not mean the same thing?  They have a virtually identical effect, meaning they're pretty much equally helpful.