# My non-answer was appropriate under the circumstances

Tags: discussion, moderation

I posted a non-answer to a question that's about to be closed.  It got deleted by a moderator, with a comment that a 12K rep person should know better.

Believe it or not, I knew what I was doing.  The question revealed no effort at answering it on the questioner's part.  The questioner had a rep of 1.  There were 3 votes to close the question.

So I figured I was doing the questioner a favor by telling him to do a search on "powershell ram info", figuring that would get him all the answers he needed.

Yeah, sure.  I know that's not an answer.  Under normal circumstances, I would never post such a thing as an answer, even though sometimes I have been specifically thanked for providing the right buzzwords for a questioner 
to find valuable web pages.  But these were not normal circumstances.  A newcomer might just not know better than to ask  a question with no effort to find an answer,  and actually doing the search would just about guarantee him an answer.

So I'm asking moderation to take a second look at this case, and at the policy in general.  Do we really want to blow off people who wander in and post a question in the wrong way?  Isn't pointing them at the answer the better way to go?  I understand that we don't want to dilute the base of valuable answers with a lot of these things.  But isn't it still the best way to go in cases like this one?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704015/check-total-ram-on-startup-and-display-message-if-its-below-a-certain-amount/40704210?noredirect=1#comment68645392_40704210

Comment: Well, your answer clearly wasn't an appropriate answer. At least VLQ. So what are you bothering about? _"Do a google search ..."_ Are you serious? That might be even considered as a _non constructive_ comment.

Comment: As a comment, this might have worked. As an answer… well, yes, you should have known better. The likelihood of questions like that getting answers like that is *exactly why* we close those questions. A newcomer (or indeed anyone) who asks a question wrong isn't entitled to an answer, since it won't help anyone else, just an explanation (brief or otherwise) of what's wrong with the question. And "use the search, Luke" is by definition useless for all future visitors who must have known how to search in order to *find* the question in the first place.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the day I can't point someone to a simple Google search that solves the OP's problem in full will be the last day I'm hanging out on Stack Overflow. (I agree it has no business being an answer, though.)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321458/17034

Comment: Sometimes you win, sometimes you learn.  I recently picked up these words of wisdom, and i can apply them here.  The most helpful answer  was one of the answers pointed to by the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 21):

There's this thing about being baited into a response.  If something causes one to react a certain way, they can claim that they were indeed baited into responding in a specific fashion.

From what I'm reading of this disposition, you believe that you were baited into the response you gave due to the fact that the OP asked an overly broad question.

***However***, and this is a big "however"...

## You shouldn't have taken the bait.

The question was too broad.  The sum total of your interaction with it should have been to close it as too broad, and downvote if you were feeling particularly onerous.  Your answer *didn't* add any value to the situation, and a moderator looking at only your answer (and sans context) would only see snark and an unnecessary "go Google this"-type of answer.

If you wanted to point them at an answer, then you would've had a duplicate lined up for them which discusses the creation of such a batch file.

Comment: Well, that's that.

Comment: I honestly don't think I was deliberately baited.