# Merge "First Posts" and "Late Answers" queue into a more meaningful and bigger one

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I'm not the first one to notice that [First Posts and Late Answers queues nearly always empty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252255/13131437).
In that question, the "answer" suggests that this is simply because the posts are reviewed too quickly due to only requiring one reviewer.

However, I also notice that the "recent reviews" queue barely budges. That leads me to think that not many posts appear in the First Posts queue altogether (and that a quick burndown is not the only cause of the queue's emptiness).

I find that strange, as new users post questions all the time... a big part of the phenomenon that [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/1313143).

If it is not currently so, I think we should include **all** first posts of new users; and perhaps expand to include also consequential posts of users whose posts are often not received well (i.e. their rep stays low, which should be an indicator).

In case my second suggestion gets implemented, the review queue might be renamed to "Posts from low reps" or something similar, and perhaps it can even be merged with the Late Answers queue (the lateness of the answer doesn't indicate possible low quality; the fact that it's from a new user does).

As a positive side effect, the new/merged review queue would allow new users who get it right from the first time to attract more upvotes quickly so they get a rep boost to get them "launched" on the site.

Comment: I *think* (purely from memory, no sources) first posts truly is all first posts, and late answers is "late answer + newish user". Assuming thats correct then your first suggestion is already in place, but your second one is a pretty good idea - though I prefer [Brad's suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252255/first-posts-and-late-answers-queues-nearly-always-empty) on a similar question to increased reviewers per post.

Comment: Not all new posts or late answers appear in the queues; IIRC posts that are already being handled by the community (sufficient activity such as editing, comments or voting) then the post doesn't have to go to those queues. Also, a post can end up in multiple queues, but if you handled it in one, you won't be shown it again in another. This includes the low-quality queue, and if you voted to close a question, the close review queue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you sure about that?  I'm almost certain I've seen a few posts in more than one queue.

Comment: @Dan: yes, I am sure. I always notice when a review in one queue drops the number of pending reviews by exactly 1 in the other queues.